# Conversion of a conv layer to fc layer and vice vers sa?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision, classification

I just wanna know if it's possible to convert a conv layer to a fully connected one and then return back to the conv layer ?

Comment: Hi Yassine and welcome to Stack Overflow.
Can you give some more information about your problem?
Also have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask where you can find more info about asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a matter of ensuring that the input is the correct shape. I assume you are using keras.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, Reshape

# Add a convolution to the network (previous layer called some_input)

c1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', name='first_conv')(some_input)

# Now reshape using 'Flatten'
f1 = Flatten(name='flat_c1')(c1)

# Now add a dense layer with 10 nodes
dense1 = Dense(10, activation='relu', name='dense1')(f1)

# Now add a dense layer, making sure it has the right number of nodes for my next conreshape8v layer.
dense2 = Dense(784, activation='relu', name='dense2')(dense1)
reshape2 = Reshape((7, 7, 16), name='reshape2')(dense2)

#Now back to convolutions (up or down)
c2 = Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', 
                      name='conv2')(reshape2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help I will check it out, is it possible to backpropagate through this model normally ?

Comment: Yes. Flatten and Reshape are keras layers, just like Dense and Conv2D, so they behave the same way regarding backprop.

Comment: if this answer solved your question, consider marking it as the answer.

Comment: Why did you add a dense layer of 10 after flattening? Shouldn't we just go directly to dense2 ?

Comment: I only added this layer to show that you can go to a Dense layer with an arbitrary number of nodes. You could go straight to 784 if you'd like to.